# convert WSG84 gps coordinate to x y cartesian coordinate on a plane

Tags: android, gps, 2d, coordinates

I'm working on an android application which can track movements. My problem is that I need to convert gps coordinates to **2-d coordinate on a plane**.

The coordinates which I obtain now are in WSG84 format. I need those coordinates because a I need to compute the distance between a point and a line in order to understand if I'm getting too far from a pre-defined path. The area in which I'm working on is not big in respect to the whole earth, so I think it's okay to not care about z axis.

I have no map, so I just need to compute these coordinates in background. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

> I need to compute the distance between a point and a line in order to understand if I'm getting too far from a pre-defined path

seems to be the key question you are posing. So that is what I will answer.

In a strict sense, converting from spherical to euclidean coordinates is not possible, which is why people invented to the UTM system among many others. The problem with using UTM for your purpose is that a given lat/lon may be in different regions, so the (x,y) pairs will not correlate usefully.

Assuming you have three points A, B and P, where A & B define the start and end of your line, and P is the point you want to know about, then my best suggestion is to:

- calculate the great circle distance (d) from P to B
- calculate the bearing from the P to B (theta)
- calculate the bearing from A to B (alpha)

**If the points are actually very close to each other** then the space you are working in is locally euclidean, so the distance from the line from A to B is:

```
d sin(alpha - theta)
```

There are numerous online references on calculating great circle distance and bearing in Java for WGS84. eg.

http://openmap.bbn.com/svn/openmap/trunk/src/openmap/com/bbn/openmap/proj/GreatCircle.java

...is just one of many.

Comment: Thanks @RabidMutant , i think this solution can work, but it depends by what you mean for "very close to each other". The area on which i'm working is almost the whole city of Rome

Comment: Rome is fine. Rome to Paris, less so.

Comment: There are also many tools for calculating distance bearing. Once you have written your code I suggest testing it by comparing with online tools.